# Power set code showing segmentation fault

Tags: c++

A recursive code to find power set of string is showing error and out of memory.

```
void recur(string a,string b,int i=0) // Recursive fun 
{ 
  int n=a.size();
  if(i==n)         //returns if becomes equal to the size of  array
  {
    cout<<b<<endl;
    return ;
  }
  recur(a,b,i++); //calls without append
  recur(a,b+a[i],i++); //calls with append
}
```

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger. That way you could see what is happening when you execute the code.

Comment: Is it intentioanl that you call `recur` with different `i`? This will garantuee a endless recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i++` doesn't do what you want it to do in this context, it increments the variable `i` and returns the value before the increment.  For example

```cpp
int i = 0;
cout << i++; // prints 0
cout << i;   // prints 1
```

You could use [pre-increment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) like `++i`, which evaluates to the value after the increment.

Also for `recur(a, b + a[i], ++i);`, the evaluation order of the parameters is unspecified, so the value of `a[i]` is unspecified.  I suggest not using increment operators at all in this case, as it just makes the code harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you call the function as `recur(a,b);` then in this line

```
recur(a,b,i++); //calls without append
```

`i` is still `0`. That line will call the function again with exact same parameters and you get a stackoverflow due to infininte recursion.